# Drag and drop files into WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, drag-and-drop

I need to drop an image file into my WPF application. I currently have a event firing when I drop the files in, but I don't know how what to do next. How do I get the Image? Is the `sender` object the image or the control?

```
private void ImagePanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //what next, dont know how to get the image object, can I get the file path here?
}
```

Answer (score 259, accepted):

This is basically what you want to do.

```
private void ImagePanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
  {
    // Note that you can have more than one file.
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

    // Assuming you have one file that you care about, pass it off to whatever
    // handling code you have defined.
    HandleFileOpen(files[0]);
  }
}
```

Also, don't forget to actually hook up the event in XAML, as well as setting the `AllowDrop` attribute.

```
<StackPanel Name="ImagePanel" Drop="ImagePanel_Drop" AllowDrop="true">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: awesome works a charm, just swapped "HandleFileOpen(files[0]);" to "foreach(string file in files) { Openfile(file); }" - Thanks :)

Comment: @Matteo Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry :) I mean the drag & drop doesn't work. ­`AllowDrop` is set to True but the `Drop` event handler is never called. When I drag a file over the window, I see a "denied" circular symbol

Comment: @Matteo I'm having the save problem. How exactly did you fix this?

Comment: I used a `Grid` as root element, with a `Border` inside with the `Background` property set to something (white is fine, but not transparent). Inside the `Border` I put the actual content.

Comment: Setting the background to transparent worked fine for me when trying to drop onto a Grid. Apparently you need a background so the hit test happens. Thanks to this blog entry: http://codeinreview.com/136/enabling-drag-and-drop-over-a-grid-in-wpf/

Comment: One real Gotcha is that if you run VisualStudio as Admin - debug your app - and drag from FileExplorer as non admin the security context is different and no drag events will trigger. Costed me 30 minutes of life.

Answer (score 36):

The image file is contained in the `e` parameter, which is an instance of the [`DragEventArgs` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.drageventargs.aspx).
(The `sender` parameter contains a reference to the object that raised the event.)

Specifically, check the [`e.Data` member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.drageventargs.data.aspx); as the documentation explains, this returns a reference to the data object ([`IDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.idataobject.aspx)) that contains the data from the drag event.

The `IDataObject` interface provides a number of methods for retrieving the data object that you're after. You'll probably want to start by calling the [`GetFormats` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557793.aspx) in order to find out the format of the data that you're working with. (For example, is it an actual image or simply the path to an image file?)

Then, once you've identified the format of the file being dragged in, you'll call one of the specific overloads of the `GetData` method to actually retrieve the data object in a particular format.

Answer (score 24):

Additionally to answer of A.R. please note that if you want to use `TextBox` to drop you have to know following stuff.

`TextBox` seems to have already some default handling for `DragAndDrop`. If your data object is a `String`, it simply works. Other types are not handled and you get the **Forbidden mouse effect** and your Drop handler is never called.

It seems like you can enable your own handling with `e.Handled` to **true** in a `PreviewDragOver` event handler.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox AllowDrop="True"    x:Name="RtbInputFile"      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

**C#**

```
RtbInputFile.Drop += RtbInputFile_Drop;            
RtbInputFile.PreviewDragOver += RtbInputFile_PreviewDragOver;

private void RtbInputFile_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void RtbInputFile_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
     {
                // Note that you can have more than one file.
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                var file = files[0];                
                HandleFile(file);  
     }
}
```

Comment: A.R.'s example misses the PreviewDragOver handler, which is kinda important to make it all come together. Kudos.