# DragDrop from WinForms to WPF issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have old `WinForms` application with DragDrop functionality (without any source code). Now I need to create new WPF application which can receive some data from old one with DragDrop. But DragDrop isn't working in WPF app and any events: `DragEnter`, `DragOver`, `DragLeave`, `Drop` doesn't fire. I've created other simple WinForms application only with DragDrop functionality and it's working OK. Also, I can do DragDrop from this simple WinForms app to WPF app.

I've tried to run my apps "As Administrator" and without this - nothing changed.
Does anybody know, how to fix this or what is root cause or can be the root cause of such strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

- Have you set the (`AllowDrop="true"`) in wpf xaml?
- and if that was yes, do you handle the `Drop` event for the capturing form or control?

see this question on stackoverflow.com for more details:
[WPF Drag and Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662509/drag-and-drop-files-into-wpf)

Comment: Yes, of course. As I said, I have 3 applications: old one with Drag functionality, new WPF with Drop functionality and test WinForms with DragAndDrop functionality. And works only: Old -> test WinForms, Test WinForms -> WPF, but my goal - Old -> WPF.

Comment: Also, I've tried to use RegisterDragDrop from ole32 library, but it has returned error code.

Comment: @ArturKorop I'm not that familiar with WPF, but the same principle applies from C# WinForms. sometimes you have to explicitly handle the same exact type from FileFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to solve the issue. The reason - the old app use RegisterDragDrop for OleDataFormat, but new WPF - use RegisterDragDrop for DataFormat. The solution - set AllowDrop to false, and use RegisterDragDrop from ole32.dll for OleDataFormat with custom IDropTarget interface or from WinForms library.